# what happens if am declaring future of method in scala?

Tags: scala

What happens if am going to declare the method as future and I am going to call that method multiple times.

```
def futureMethod():Future[String]={
Future{
..............
some functionality
..............

"test"
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is very vague. State clearly what exactly do you want to know.

Comment: If you call `futureMethod()` multiple times you get multiple `Future[String]` values. The actual amount of concurrency you can achieve is system dependent. (CPUs, cores, thread pool restrictions, etc.) What is the point of your question?

Answer (score 0):

Since that's a method and since `Future` is eager (i.e. is runs immediately), every time you call `futureMethod` the computation inside `Future { }` will be run and a new feature will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You did not declare the method **as** future, you simply declared a method that **returns** a `Future`.

Each time you call your function it will create and return a new `Future`.

You can use the methods on that `Future` to process the data generated by the function inside the `Future` when it becomes available.